# What is the concept behind finding the data type of this vector

Tags: r

What will the following code return?

MyVector <- c(12, 456, 34.5, 23, 55, "34hello")

typeof(MyVector)

Ans is character, but what is the logic behind it?

Comment: See `help("c")`: "The output type is determined from the highest type of the components in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex < character < list < expression."